# How to simplify huge expressions when the final form is known?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am solving a system of equations of the following type:

$$a_1 \cdot f[13,0] + b_1 \cdot f[13,1] + ... + k_1 \cdot f[13,11] + l_1 (d[12] - f[13,12]) = m_1, \tag{1.1}$$
$$a_2 \cdot f[13,0] + b_2 \cdot f[13,1] + ... + k_2 \cdot f[13,11] + l_2 (d[12] - f[13,12]) = m_2, \tag{1.2}$$
$$ ... , $$

for the `f[13,j]` ($j \leq 11$) and for `d[12]-f[13,12]`. Mathematica manages to solve the system of equations, but the results are huge!

[image]

I happen to know (from coefficients `f[i,j]` for $i \leq 12$) that they always take this form when simplified:

$$f[i,j] = g^8 n^ 2\frac{a + b \cdot \pi^2}{c \cdot \pi^6}, \quad d[j] - f[j+1,j] = g^8 n^2 \frac{d + e \cdot \pi^2 + f \cdot \log 2}{g \cdot \pi^6} \tag{2}$$

where $a, b, c, d, e, f, g$ are just numbers and $g^8 n^2$ is a symbolic prefactor common to all expressions. For $i-j$ odd with $i-j\neq 1$, $b=0$ always. I left `ExpandAll // Simplify` work overnight on `f[13,0]`, but it was still running as I woke up! I ran into similar problems for the previous coefficients, but I always managed to simplify a couple of them, feed them back into the system of equations, simplify again a couple, feed them back, etc...

In this case I tried simplifying the numerator and denominator separately without success. I need to find a stable solution, as I wish to go up to $i=15$. How could I proceed?

I cannot post a MWE since the system of equations is so huge, but you can download a dump file containing the solutions [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmfgkimjj0irk4l/sol1.mx?dl=0). To load it, just put the file sol1.mx in the same folder as a new Mathematica notebook containing:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
<< sol1.mx
sol1[[1,1]]
```

This should display the solution to `f[13,0]`. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Note that Mathematica has no problem computing the numerical value with `N`. I tried to guess the form given in eq. (2) from there, but I have not been successful so far.

Comment: I think I found a workaround. For all the expressions with $i-j$ odd, I can multiply by $\pi^6$, get the numerical value with `N` and then use `Rationalize` to get the closed form. Increasing the precision of `N` should lead to convergence of the rational expression. The results can be fed in the system of equations, and the even ones can now be simplified easily. It worked very well for $i=13$, I am now trying this method for $i=14$...